# KeyError exception in List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function:

```
def calculate(blob, count_per_data):
   return geometric_mean( [score_per_count[ count_per_data[data] ] for data in combinations(blob)] )
```

The problem with my code is that if `data` is not found in `count_per_data` I get an exception. Instead, I wish `count_per_data["unknown"]` to evaluate to 0, i.e. `"unknown"`'s count is 0.

In turn, the value 0 exists in `score_per_count` and is not equal to 0. In other words, the score associated with a count of 0 is not itself 0.

How would you recommend I fix the above code to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to make sure that, the `data` exists in `count_per_data` and the value of `count_per_data` exists in `score_per_count`, you can use the list comprehension as a filter, like this

```
return geometric_mean([score_per_count[count_per_data[data]] for data in  combinations(blob) if data in count_per_data and count_per_data[data] in score_per_count])
```

More readable version,

```
return geometric_mean([score_per_count[count_per_data[data]]
     for data in combinations(blob)
     if data in count_per_data and count_per_data[data] in score_per_count])
```

But, **if you want to use default values** when key is not found in a dictionary, then you can use `dict.get`. Quoting from [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) docs,

```
get(key[, default])
```

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If
>   default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never
>   raises a KeyError.

You can use it, like this

```
count_per_data.get(data, 0)
```

If `data` is not found in `count_per_data`, `0` will be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Add conditions to the comprehension list:

```
return geometric_mean([score_per_count[count_per_data[data]] for data in combinations(blob) if data in count_per_data.keys() and count_per_data[data]] in geometric_mean.keys() else 0)
```